# Can we change the array range of all named references in Excel at once?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In my Excel file, I have about 50 named ranges. 
For example

`A1:A35` is named as ALPHA

`B1:B35` is named as BETA
and so on.

Now all of these end at Row 35 but say in future I get a bigger data set and I want to increase the array of all these 50 named ranges to say:

`A1:A100` to be Named as ALPHA

`B1:B100` to be Named as BETA

Is there a way that can be done using VBA or any other suggestion?

Comment: If you have dynamic range either table based or formula based, it will automatically adjust for addition in rows or columns. Reference <http://www.contextures.com/xlNames01.html#videodynamic>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code sets the range of a named range

```
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="Beta", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C2:R35C2"
```

`R1C2:R35C2` This part defines the range you want (R = Row, C = Column)

You can change the range of the named range by changing the R35 to whatever range you need it to be

`Name:="Beta"` This is the name of the named range, change this to what you range you want to change it to

Let me knwo if you need anything further explained